# Multiple images with UI Image Picker in SWIFT

Tags: swift, uiimagepickercontroller

Im trying to add second image view with the option to choose another image, so what ever photo is chosen can be set onto the second imageview. Kind of like a WhatsApp, when selecting the multiple images to send. I've tried a couple of options, but couldn't really solve the problem. This is my code working only for one image view.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.PhotoLibrary) {
            let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary

            self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

    imageView.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true

    imageView2.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    imageView2.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
    imageView2.clipsToBounds = true

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Did you got any solution for this . . am also facing the same issue. I need to select multiple images & am using UIImagePickerController.

Comment: @AnoojKrishnanG Hey did u get to do the same using UIImagePickerController or finally used 3rd party framework.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there is no simple API that allows you to use this, you will need to create an intermediate view controller which stores the images you have already selected, either that or you have to create a custom Image Picker, which recquires a lot more effort. [This is a link](http://code4app.net/ios/BRNImagePickerSheet/5434f275e247416212bb6368) to some open source code that replicates the iPhone's iMessage way of selecting multiple images. It's nice but might not be exactly what you need.